# A mapping from Vector-collection with objects (parties to their top candidates)

Tags: scala, object, dictionary, max

I have to get a mapping from parties to their top candidates.

`Map[String, Candidate]`

That is, a mapping from parties to their top candidates. That is a Map whose keys are the names of all the parties that have candidates in this district. For each key, the value is the candidate from that party with the most votes.

Here is Candidate-class (without methods etc.):

```
// @param name  the candidate's name
// @param votes the number of votes received by the candidate
// @param party the name

class Candidate(val name: String, val votes: Int, val party: String) {
  ...
}
```

And this is District-class (without methods etc.)

```
class District(val name: String, val seats: Int, val candidates: Vector[Candidate]){

  def topCandidate: Candidate = { // Not implemented  }   

  ...
}

// there is collection of candidates
val candidates: Vector[Candidate] = { ... }
```

Comment: Where that map should be?

Comment: its a return value of method that is member of District-calss

def topCandidatesByParty: Map[String, Candidate] = ...

Comment: What is topCandidate inside District? and is it relevant to the question?

Answer (score 1):

This is a one liner:

```
def topCandidatesByParty(district:District) =
      district.candidates.groupBy(_.party).mapValues(_.maxBy(_.votes))
```

Complete test case:

```
object districts extends App {
  case class Candidate(val name: String, val votes: Int, val party: String) {

}
  case class District(val name: String, val seats: Int, val candidates: Vector[Candidate]){

  }
  val district = District("Berkshire", 1, Vector[Candidate](
      Candidate("Bob", 100, "Tories"),
      Candidate("Jim", 200, "Tories"),
      Candidate("Mary", 500, "Tories"),
      Candidate("Dave", 100, "Whigs"),
      Candidate("Jack", 500, "Whigs")

  ))


def topCandidatesByParty(district:District) =
      district.candidates.groupBy(_.party).mapValues(_.maxBy(_.votes))

println(topCandidatesByParty(district).mkString)
}
```

Output:

```
Whigs -> Candidate(Jack,500,Whigs)Tories -> Candidate(Mary,500,Tories)
```

Comment: Wow, that's beatiful, concise and conveys the meaning through Code. +1. I'm just too narrow-mindedly using `foldLeft` for almost everything.

Comment: Thanks a lot , thats awesome! One line of code : "district.candidates.groupBy(_.party).mapValues(_.maxBy(_.votes))"

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get a `Map[String, Candidate]` from a `Vector[Candidate]`. For example, you could use a `foldLeft` to get what you desire.

In the following, I made the `Candidate` and the `District` case classes. This is simply for convenience, and the approach can also be applied if you do not declare them as case classes. The code would only become slightly more verbose as you could not automatically pattern match.

```
case class Candidate(name: String, votes: Int, party: String)

case class District(name: String, seats: Int, candidates: Vector[Candidate]){
  def topCandidatePerParty: Map[String, Candidate] =
    (candidates foldLeft Map.empty[String, Candidate]){
      case (topCandidates, nextCandidate@Candidate(_, votes, party)) =>
        topCandidates.get(party) match {
          case None => topCandidates + (party -> nextCandidate)
          case Some(Candidate(_, topVotes, _)) =>
            if (topVotes < votes) topCandidates + (party -> nextCandidate) else topCandidates
        }
    }
}
```

What does this do:

- It takes the candidate vector and iterates over it, accumulating a result of type `Map[String, Candidate]`
- The accumulator is initialized to be the empty map
- For each candidate, it checks whether the party of this candidate is already a key in the map. This is done by checking whether `topCandidates.get` is `None`.
- If the party is not yet present in the map, add the candidate to the map. `a -> b` is just a shorthand for `(a, b)` and reads like `a` maps to `b`.
- If the party is already present with a different candidate, check if the new candidate has more votes
- If the new candidate has more votes, put the new candidate in the map, otherwise, keep the old map.

Comment: Cannot get that one to work, IDE says: val error:(nextCandidate, Candidate)

at this line :  case (topCandidates, nextCandidate@Candidate(_, votes, party)) 

and other one at tis line:
case Some(Candidate(_, topVotes, _)) =>

Comment: Hmm... well... it does compile for me (with Scala 2.11) Which version of Scala are you using? Here's the cmplete code if you're interested: http://pastie.org/9619643